# GWT is unable to instantiate an interface, but can instantiate an abstract class?

Tags: java, generics, gwt

If I have the following:

```
public interface GetItemRequest<T extends FooBase>
{
    public long getId();
}

public class GetFooRequest implements GetItemRequest<Foo>
{
  //snip..
}

public interface GetService extends RemoteService
{
   public <T extends FooBase> T get( GetItemRequest<T> request );
}
```

And on server, I have the following execute method, which executes the request via GWT-RPC:

```
public class GetServiceImpl<T extends FooBase>
          extends RemoteServiceServlet
          implements GetSerice<T>

{
   public T get( GetItemRequest<T> request)
   { 
     //snip
   }
}
```

That does not work, and it gives the error:

> Exception:
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException:
>   Invalid type signature for com.xxx.GetFooRequest

However, if I change `GetItemRequest` to be an abstract class rather than an interface, i.e:

```
public abstract class GetItemRequest<T extends FooBase>
{
    public abstract long getId();
}
```

And have `GetFooRequest` extend from `GetItemRequest<Foo>` rather than `implement` it, then the request works just fine.

Strangely however, `GetFooRequest` must be completely abstract in order for this to work. If I try to implement any method, like `getId()` in `GetItemRequest` rather than in `GetFooRequest`, I get the same exception.

Anyone know the reason behind this strange behavior?

Comment: Did you mean `GetItemRequest<T extends FooBase>`?

Comment: @PaulBellora Yes, good catch. It was a typo here, in the real code it is `T extends FooBase`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code and its working fine with some minor changes.

There are some compilation errors in your code as well, may be due to typo mistake such as:

```
GetItemRequest<T extends FooBase>
```

---

```
public class GetServiceImpl<T extends FooBase> extends RemoteServiceServlet implements GetService
```

***Please verify it again from below code:***

**Shared:**

```
public abstract class GetItemRequest<T extends FooBase> {
    public abstract long getId();
}
```

---

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;
public class GetFooRequest  extends GetItemRequest<Foo> implements IsSerializable {
    @Override
    public long getId() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

---

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;
public class FooBase implements IsSerializable{
    ...
}
```

---

```
public class Foo extends FooBase{
    ...
}
```

**Client:**

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;
import com.gwt.test.shared.FooBase;
import com.gwt.test.shared.GetItemRequest;
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("get")
public interface GetService extends RemoteService {
    public <T extends FooBase> T get(GetItemRequest<T> request);
}
```

---

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.gwt.test.shared.FooBase;
import com.gwt.test.shared.GetItemRequest;
public interface GetServiceAsync {
    void get(GetItemRequest request, AsyncCallback<FooBase> callback);
}
```

---

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

    GetServiceAsync getService = GWT.create(GetService.class);

    getService.get(new GetFooRequest(), new AsyncCallback<FooBase>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            System.out.println("failure");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FooBase result) {
            System.out.println("success");
        }

    });

    ...
}
```

**Server:**

```
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;
import com.gwt.test.client.GetService;
import com.gwt.test.shared.Foo;
import com.gwt.test.shared.FooBase;
import com.gwt.test.shared.GetItemRequest;
public class GetServiceImpl<T extends FooBase> extends RemoteServiceServlet implements GetService {
    @Override
    public <T extends FooBase> T get(GetItemRequest<T> request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**web.xml:**

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>getServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.x.y.z.server.GetServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>getServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/context_root/get</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: In my actual code, I'm passing a `Request<? extends RequestItem>` object in my GWT-RPC requests. So what ends up getting passed to server is `Request<GetItemRequest<FooItem>>`. I understand that if you just pas `GetItemRequest<FooItem>` it will work, but the double generics is what seems to cause GWT to give a `Invalid type signature` error.

Answer (score 1):

With some changes in your code it will start working:

implements IsSerializable.

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;
public class GetFooRequest implements GetItemRequest<Foo>,IsSerializable
{
  //snip..
}
```

change return type.

```
public class GetServiceImpl<T extends FooBase>
         extends RemoteServiceServlet
         implements GetSerice<T>
  {
     public <T extends FooBase> get( GetItemRequest<T> request)
     { 
       //snip
     }
  }
```